# How to visualize char-rnn model

Tags: data-visualization, references, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras

I am looking for any resource or tutorial which can help me to understand the visualization done by Andrej Karpathy’s blog (http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) or the simpler example done here http://blog.echen.me/ .

I have a working lstm model and found out (I think) how to get intermediate layers from my model (using keras) but didn't figure out what to do after.

In Karpathy's paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02078) they look for interpretable cells but it's not clear to me how to look for them or how to select them.

Examples of visualization from Karpathy's blog post:

[image: Karpathy rnn]

Examples of visualization from Chen's blog post:

[image: Chen lstm]

(I will add some dummy code asap.)

Edit 1: add some pictures
Edit 2: reformulate

Comment: Note to close voters: this is a reference request question (which is on-topic here, and we have a tag for it) about visualization (also on-topic here), so I believe the topic is firmly on-topic!

Comment: Any chance you could include an example image? Sadly internet pages go offline over time (we have a severe problem with linkrot here) so future readers may not be able to access the pictures at your links. That's why we prefer questions and answers to be largely self-contained.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will add some code soon

Comment: @Silverfish The title looks misleading to me. The OP seems to understand the visualizations as he/she is explaining them to us. My impression is that this is  off-topic as the focus is how to do something in keras. How can sample code persuade us that it is on-topic? Alternatively, this perhaps should be closed as unclear what is being asked.

Comment: @vinuviduvisu If you're asking for specific code, then this is likely to be off-topic. If your focus is on explanations of principles, please make that clearer in your question.

Comment: @Nick Cox Doing the training/prediction of the network is fine. I am not asking any code about that. My question is more about how to visualize the activation process like in the examples provided. I am a bit stuck at this step. I can get the different weights associated to hidden or cell state for instance (using keras or tf). I understand the general idea from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02078.pdf (part 4.2), in which they look for interpretable cells. However, I have no clue how they "look for" them. Iteratively scanning all possible cells? Is there some kind of metric behind?

Comment: What you are saying in comments seems a little clearer than your question and different in emphasis.  So, you might consider revising your question.